# Django Ngnix Uwsgi :Could not connect to the requested server host

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I tried to follow the tutorial for deploying django app on ec2 using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04), however getting an error:

> "Could not connect to the requested server host"

When trying to deploy the first site with ref to tutorial. Only thing I changed is the server_name firstsite.com to public IP of the machine. Please help me figure, where I can find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my error,firstly it was a cache of ec2 on my browser,
Secondly,my config ngnix was a symbolic link to the ngnix was not updated.
I initially uninstalled nginx and then tried to replicate the scenario,then 
i updated my symbolic links which got my site running up

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your EC2 instance has firewall rules ([security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)) which prevent you from connecting to your app. You can follow [these directions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) to enable inbound traffic to your instance.

Comment: I will look into those directions,but the site actually worked once,tried to deploy the secondsite with ref to tutorial then the firstsite was not working